# Wi-Fi Extending Using MoCA

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet

I would like to extend the Wi-Fi in my house using a MoCA kit (like the Actiontec ECB2500CK01). All the examples I see online have the second unit running to a TV, PlayStation, etc., but I would like to run it to a router (like an AirPort Express), just to extend my network range. Does that make sense, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Your plan makes sense. The reason they picture a TV or PlayStation with their MoCA-Ethernet adapters is because if they knew you wanted to do Wi-Fi range extension over MoCA, they'd try to sell you their [Wi-Fi AP with a built-in MoCA port](http://www.actiontec.com/329.html).

I find that buying high-quality Wi-Fi APs (a.k.a. "wireless routers") is important, and I find that Wi-Fi APs that have special networking interfaces (besides Ethernet and Wi-Fi, so like HomePlug, MoCA, DSL, DOCSIS) are usually mediocre Wi-Fi APs. So I agree with your notion of buying a MoCA-Ethernet adapter that just does MoCa-to-Ethernet, and buying a high-quality AP to connect to it over Ethernet.